# count_vectorizer.vocabulary_.items() and count_vectorizer.vocabulary_ Inconsistent number of returns

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, feature-extraction

```
# create a count vectorizer object
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

# fit the count vectorizer using the text data
count_vectorizer.fit(data['text'])

# collect the vocabulary items used in the vectorizer
dictionary = count_vectorizer.vocabulary_.items()
```

To my understanding, after `count_vectorizer` fits to `data['text']`, it generates a list of features. In my case, it generated `25,257` features and these are mapped as `dict` data type when I call `count_vectorizer.vocabulary_`. Which is still `25,257` tuples. It means, it used all the features.

Problem is, when I call `count_vectorizer.vocabulary_.items()` it returns `15,142` tuples as  `dict_items`. Why the number has been reduced here? Should't all the features be used to make the `dictionary`?

Here are the lengths I'm talking about:

```
len(data['text'])  #19579
len(count_vectorizer.get_feature_names())  #25257 items
len(count_vectorizer.vocabulary_)  #25257 items
len(dictionary) #15142 items (??????)
```

Comment: Interesting.  The mismatch in the last two lines suggests that something weird is happening at the python level, not necessarily due to sklearn.  Why/when is `len(my_dict)` not equal to `len(my_dict.items())`???

Comment: I tried with a dataset of mine and I have equal results. Are you sure it has nothing to do with your dataset or working session?

Comment: @BenReiniger I am asking the same question as you. As there are lots of features I am not sure which features are missing.

Comment: Try taking the difference?  Along @EdoardoGuerriero's lines, are you running these in immediate succession?

Comment: @EdoardoGuerriero When I tried with a dummy data with only 18-20 features, I got same results too. But, in this case I'm getting the different results may be because there's a lots of feature. But this shouldn't be the case. I reset my session several times. But nothing happened

Comment: Turns out it was a session issue. I ran the whole program from beginning. now got same results. Thanks guys. A simple solution, yet saved my day. (Couldn't resist thanking though site doesn't recommend. ) @EdoardoGuerriero I think you can post the session issue as answer. It might save others day too.

Comment: @EdoardoGuerriero called it as a session problem; care to make that an answer?

Comment: @BenReiniger done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers: as Ben wrote in the comments, it is really hard in general that len(my_dict) != len(my_dict.items()). When these kind of strage behaviours happen, it is always a good practise to perform some routine checks:

- Clean your environment from every variable, even better restart the kernel and then run again your code.
- Check your code for variables with same name, be sure you're not overwriting stuff, it's easy also to end up defining functions with same name of other imported library functions.
- Try your code on different datasets, to be sure the mistake is not due to some external issue with the data.

If none of the above checks solve the mystery, then you can start thinking about a bug, a corrupted installation of a library or some other more nested problems.